# How to split a character vector based on a numeric vector for positions

Tags: r, split, strsplit

I would like to split a character vector into substrings based on a second numeric vector for the splitting points

```
vec <- "LAYRVCMTNEGHPWVSLVVQKTRLQISQDPSLNYEYLPTMGLKSFIQASLALLFGKHSQAIVENRVGGVHTVGDSGAFQLGVQFLRAWHKDARIVYIISSQKELHGLVFQDMGFTVYEYSVWDPKKLCMDPDILLNVVEQIPHGCVLVMGNIIDCKLTPSGWAKLMSM"
split.points <- c(25, 32, 55, 90, 124)
```

I would like to cut the above character vector at the positions given in the `split.points` vector into six different substrings.

It sounds very simple, but the `split` command I know works either only with specific regex (patterns) or with a set length of substrings.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can try `substring`:

```
substring(
    vec,
    c(1, split.points + 1),
    c(split.points, nchar(vec))
)
# [1] "LAYRVCMTNEGHPWVSLVVQKTRLQ"                    "ISQDPSL"                                     
# [3] "NYEYLPTMGLKSFIQASLALLFG"                      "KHSQAIVENRVGGVHTVGDSGAFQLGVQFLRAWHK"         
# [5] "DARIVYIISSQKELHGLVFQDMGFTVYEYSVWDP"           "KKLCMDPDILLNVVEQIPHGCVLVMGNIIDCKLTPSGWAKLMSM"
```

Answer (score 4):

Another alternative is to use `read.fwf`:

```
unlist(read.fwf(textConnection(vec), 
                widths = c(25, diff(split.points)), 
                as.is = TRUE), 
       use.names = FALSE)
```

which gives:

> ```
> [1] "LAYRVCMTNEGHPWVSLVVQKTRLQ"          
> [2] "ISQDPSL"                            
> [3] "NYEYLPTMGLKSFIQASLALLFG"            
> [4] "KHSQAIVENRVGGVHTVGDSGAFQLGVQFLRAWHK"
> [5] "DARIVYIISSQKELHGLVFQDMGFTVYEYSVWDP"
> ```

---

I wouldn't be surprised when your character vector originates from a data-file. In that case `read.fwf` would be especially usefull. An example:

```
vec2 <- "LAYRVCMTNEGHPWVSLVVQKTRLQISQDPSLNYEYLPTMGLKSFIQASLALLFGKHSQAIVENRVGGVHTVGDSGAFQLGVQFLRAWHKDARIVYIISSQKELHGLVFQDMGFTVYEYSVWDPKKLCMDPDILLNVVEQIPHGCVLVMGNIIDCKLTPSGWAKLMSM
LAYRVCMTNEGHPWVSLVVQKTRLQISQDPSLNYEYLPTMGLKSFIQASLALLFGKHSQAIVENRVGGVHTVGDSGAFQLGVQFLRAWHKDARIVYIISSQKELHGLVFQDMGFTVYEYSVWDPKKLCMDPDILLNVVEQIPHGCVLVMGNIIDCKLTPSGWAKLMSM"

read.fwf(textConnection(vec2), 
         widths = c(25, diff(split.points)), 
         as.is=TRUE)
```

which will give:

```
                         V1      V2                      V3                                  V4                                 V5
1 LAYRVCMTNEGHPWVSLVVQKTRLQ ISQDPSL NYEYLPTMGLKSFIQASLALLFG KHSQAIVENRVGGVHTVGDSGAFQLGVQFLRAWHK DARIVYIISSQKELHGLVFQDMGFTVYEYSVWDP
2 LAYRVCMTNEGHPWVSLVVQKTRLQ ISQDPSL NYEYLPTMGLKSFIQASLALLFG KHSQAIVENRVGGVHTVGDSGAFQLGVQFLRAWHK DARIVYIISSQKELHGLVFQDMGFTVYEYSVWDP
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `separate` from `tidyr`

```
library(tidyverse)
data_frame(vec) %>%
      separate(vec, into = paste0('vec', 1:6), sep = split.points) %>% 
      unlist(., use.names = FALSE)
#[1] "LAYRVCMTNEGHPWVSLVVQKTRLQ"                    "ISQDPSL"                                      "NYEYLPTMGLKSFIQASLALLFG"                     
#[4] "KHSQAIVENRVGGVHTVGDSGAFQLGVQFLRAWHK"          "DARIVYIISSQKELHGLVFQDMGFTVYEYSVWDP"
#[6] "KKLCMDPDILLNVVEQIPHGCVLVMGNIIDCKLTPSGWAKLMSM"
```

---

A `base R` option would be `substr`

```
unname(mapply(substr, vec, start = c(1, split.points+1), stop = c(split.points, nchar(vec))))
#[1] "LAYRVCMTNEGHPWVSLVVQKTRLQ"                    "ISQDPSL"                                      "NYEYLPTMGLKSFIQASLALLFG"                     
#[4] "KHSQAIVENRVGGVHTVGDSGAFQLGVQFLRAWHK"          "DARIVYIISSQKELHGLVFQDMGFTVYEYSVWDP"           "KKLCMDPDILLNVVEQIPHGCVLVMGNIIDCKLTPSGWAKLMSM"
```